# notifyItemChanged Animation executing multiple times?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hello all There is some weird behaviour when I add notifyItemChanged(i); the switch needs to be clicked 2 times to apply the change in the view, if i remove the line it works fine but no animation is executed, thank you all for any help :)

[here is the example of the behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3Bvd.gif)

Adapter File

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder>{

    public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv;
        TextView personName;
        TextView personAge;
        ImageView personPhoto;
        Switch personSwitch;
        TextView personInvisible;

        PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            personName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            personAge = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
            personPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            personSwitch = (Switch)itemView.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
            personInvisible = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.invisible);

        }
    }
    List<Card> persons;

    RVAdapter(List<Card> persons){
        this.persons = persons;
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return persons.size();
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v;
        Log.d("myTag", "Position " + i);
        if(i%2 == 0 || true) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, viewGroup, false);
        }
        else {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview2, viewGroup, false);
        }
        PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, final int i) {
        Log.d("myTag", "Position2 " + i);
        personViewHolder.personName.setText(persons.get(i).name);
        personViewHolder.personAge.setText(persons.get(i).age);
        personViewHolder.personPhoto.setImageResource(persons.get(i).photoId);
        personViewHolder.personSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
                new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        if(isChecked)
                        {
                            Log.d("myTag", "ACTIVATED " + i);

                            personViewHolder.personInvisible.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            personViewHolder.personInvisible.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Log.d("myTag", "DISABLE " + i);

                        }
                        Log.d("myTag", "CHANGED " + i);
                        //RVAdapter.this.notifyItemChanged(i);

                    }
                }
        );
    }



    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }
}
```

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Card> cards;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initializeData();

        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(cards);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    // This method creates an ArrayList that has three Person objects
// Checkout the project associated with this tutorial on Github if
// you want to use the same images.
    private void initializeData(){
        cards = new ArrayList<>();
        cards.add(new Card("Emma Wilson", "23 years old", R.mipmap.ic_launcher,false));
        cards.add(new Card("Lavery Maiss", "25 years old", R.mipmap.ic_launcher,false));
        cards.add(new Card("Lillie Watts", "35 years old", R.mipmap.ic_launcher,false));
        cards.add(new Card("ANOTER Watts", "35 years old", R.mipmap.ic_launcher,false));

    }

}
```

Layout File

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        card_view:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        >

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/invisible"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:text="Invisible TEXT"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone"
                card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch1"

                />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/switch1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Show Text"
                card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image"
                card_view:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image"
                card_view:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/image" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/image"


                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_goneMarginBottom="0dp"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" />

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                card_view:layout_constraintGuide_begin="57dp" />


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't call notifyItemChanged from your Adapter. This method should be invoked when some data is changed outside your adapter and current UI does not represent this data. In your case you change data inside the adapter so no need to redraw item

Comment: Say what? So when you, for instance, change text inside of a `ViewHolder`, from where should  you then update the item? From the Adapter..

Comment: @HB. In case you change text inside ViewHolder - there is no need to invoke notifyItemChanged, but if the data itself is changed, for example, persons[0].name="Some other name" then you should notify your adapter about this change.